# Python: cycle through elements in list reversing when the end is reached

Tags: python, list, cycle

I have a list that looks like:

```
a = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10']
```

I need to cycle through this list one element at a time but when the end of the list is reached, the cycle needs to be *reversed*.

For example, using [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

```
from itertools import cycle
a_cycle = cycle(a)
for _ in range(30):
    print a_cycle.next()
```

I get:

```
01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10
```

but what I need is:

```
01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 10, 09, 08, 07, 06, 05, 04, 03, 02, 01, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10
```

I need to cycle through `a` for a fixed number of times, say 200.

Comment: Do you need this to be indefinite?

Comment: @ScironicI need it to run until an outer `for` loop (not shown in question) exhausts its elements.

Comment: Dimo414's solution should work, you can just cycle through that.

Comment: That was me, sorry. I sloppily misread your code. Saw the `i in range(30)` and the leading zeros and thought you're among the many people not showing actual data. I undid the vote. Wouldn't have happened if you had written `for _ in range(30)`, btw, as that's the convention for values you're not going to use. But it was really my fault and I should take a break.

Comment: No worries, I removed the question about the downvote after realizing it was gone. I'll change `i` for `_`, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can [`cycle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) the [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) of your `a` and [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?#reversed) `a`, eg:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice, chain

a = range(1, 11)
b = reversed(a)
c = cycle(chain(a, b))
d = list(islice(c, 100)) # `c` is infinite - hence the `islice` to stop at some point...
```

Which gives you:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

**Note**: If `a` is an exhaustable iterator, you will need to make a copy of `a` first. But given your example, this will be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Do you actually need to *cycle* through the list, as in go forward and backwards forever?  Or just [`.reverse()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) the list?

```
print a + a[::-1]
```

Will do what you describe.  The [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) built-in also works, but you need to `chain()` it, as it returns an iterator, e.g.:

```
print list(itertools.chain(a, reversed(a)))
```

You can call `itertools.cycle()` on either result to get an infinite iterator of the list concatenated with its reverse.

Comment: `.reverse()` doesn't return anything so wouldn't work. use `a+a[::-1]` instead

Comment: @Scironic is correct, `a.reverse()` returns `None`.

Comment: your edit still doesn't work as lists are mutable, so assigning it to a new variable and reversing it reverses both lists. You would need to copy to do this, but it's easier to use a reverse slice

Answer (score 2):

```
def forwardback(lst):
    tot = len(lst)
    while 1:
        for i in xrange(tot):
            yield lst[i]
        for i in xrange(tot-1,-1,-1):
            yield lst[i]
```

or (using `cycle`'s approach, which works for all iterators)

```
def forwardback(lst):
    saved = []
    for elem in lst:
        yield elem
        saved.append(elem)
    while saved:
        for elem in reversed(saved):
            yield elem
        for elem in saved:
            yield elem
```

Comment: Note: `i` is not yet defined when you do `yield lst[i]` in your 2nd code block. And why use indices when you can directly iterate over iterables? You can use `reversed()` to do reverse iteration on any iterable, and extended slice notation on things like lists, eg  `for v in reversed(saved):` or `for v in saved[::-1]:`.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed typo. Had copied previous program and edited it. Also, you're right about `reversed`. I wasn't aware it returned an iterator. I didn't want to use more space and re-recreate the list.

Answer (score 2):

Make a copy of list a, reverse it, then append it.

```
a = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10']
b = a[:]
b.reverse()
a = a + b
```

or based on a comment suggestion.

```
a = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10']
b = a[::-1]
a = a + b
```

Comment: see dimo414s answer, you can just use reverse slicing: `a[::-1]`